# Hard time applying noise canceling fix

Tags: pulseaudio, microphone

I am new to ubuntu and linux, not a programmer, and I would like to fix background noise that I am getting from mic. I found other people had the same issue with the same soundcard (ALC892) and tried applying the following fix:

[Microphone - static background noise suppression](https://askubuntu.com/questions/421671/microphone-static-background-noise-suppression/497559#497559)

Unfortunately, probably due to my computing limitations, I was unable to do it. My issues so far were:
1) I don't know if I have "libjack-jackd2-0" or "libjack0". I assumed I had "libjack-jackd2-0" and ran the commands suggested and things seemed to work, but not sure if this was correct.
2) When I get to "building the package" and run "dpkg-buildpackage -d -us -uc -nc" I get the following error: 
debian/rules:60: *** comandos começam antes do primeiro alvo.  Pare.
dpkg-buildpackage: erro: debian/rules build deu erro de saída estado 2

I am running Ubuntu in portuguese but the translation of the error would be:
debian/rules:60 *** commands begin before first target. Stop.
dpkg-buildpackage: error: debian/rules build got an exit state 2 error

Any help would be apreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Hi Gabriel, the quick and easy answer can be found here http://askubuntu.com/a/765024/7035